# How to make functions in <script setup > called by other components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

i have a function in < script setup > component, it not called in this component,i want use this function in other componet.

```
const playAudioType = (type) => {
          if (type === 'play') {
              store.setPlayStatus(!isPlayed.value);
              store.setPlayIndex(playIndex.value);
          } else {
              changeSong(type);
          }
      };
```

this code is grey in vs code

but when i use this function in other componet ,he can not recognize this function.

```
 const playSongStates = (state) => {
      audioRef.value.playAudioType(state);
    };
```

if use normal < script > i can return this function.

but in < scrtipt setup > how could i do

Comment: `.value` suffix is only used with variables - not with functions. If you want to refer to a function in another component - you first get a reference to that other component (e.g. through `$refs`) and then simply call that function as a method of the component object from your reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `defineExpose` to expose variables and methods from `<script setup>` to other components.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const a = 1
const b = ref(2)

defineExpose({
  a,
  b
})
</script>
```

In parent component:

```
      childRef.value.a
```

[Further read](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose)

Answer (score 0):

As @manniL already wrote you can expose properties with defineExpose (https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose).

This only works within a parent-child relationship, and should normally not be used for reusable functions. The better solution would be to use composables (https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html)